# Update records with JOIN command

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that works great and shows me where the tbl_staff.staff_id and tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id values do not match.

```
    SELECT
tbl_staff.staff_id,
tbl_staff.username,
tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_name,
tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id
    FROM
    tbl_staff
    JOIN tbl_lead ON tbl_staff.username = tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_name
    AND tbl_staff.staff_id <> tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id;
```

The query returns values like this where you can see the 1014 does not match the 1004.

```
1014    bubba   bubba   1004
```

I want to update the value in the tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id to the same value as is found in tbl_staff.staff_id.

I tried to insert a SET command but it's giving me a generic syntax error:

```
        SELECT
    tbl_staff.staff_id,
    tbl_staff.username,
    tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_name,
    tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id
        FROM
        tbl_staff
        JOIN tbl_lead ON tbl_staff.username = tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_name
        AND tbl_staff.staff_id <> tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id
SET tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id=tbl_staff.staff_id ;
```

The actual error is:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SET tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id=tbl_staff.staff_id' at line
>   10

I tried to change the SELECT to and UPDATE command using this question but still could not get it working:  [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: Edit your question an include the full text of the error.

Comment: error is now included

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. Take a look at the syntax for the UPDATE command. That is what you want to use, not a SELECT command.

Comment: I tried using update with this question and could not get it working:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE tbl_lead
JOIN tbl_staff ON tbl_staff.username = tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_name
SET tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id = tbl_staff.staff_id 
WHERE tbl_staff.staff_id <> tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
UPDATE tbl_staff, tbl_lead 
  SET tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_id = tbl_staff.staff_id
  WHERE tbl_staff.username = tbl_lead.rlog_create_user_name
```

Comment: `tbl_lead` is updated with the corresponding value from `tbl_staff`